# Check application to sharing text with UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

For sharing message I use `UIActivityViewController`.

Code:

```
let textShare = [ "text" ]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textShare , applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self?.view
present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I need to change text for different application, so my question is:

How I can check what application(for example mail or skype), user choose for sharing text?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Use **completionWithItemsHandler** of **UIActivityViewController**
to telled which application selected by  user shared the content.

```
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
    if !completed {
        // User canceled 
        return
    }
    // User completed activity
}

self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: does not fit, because this completion calls after user send text or cancel